# Need help converting nested join query to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

need some assistance making a query work in Laravel.

I've tried this query outside laravel and it works:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
        stories AS t
    JOIN
        ( SELECT created_at
          FROM stories
          WHERE id = 126
        ) AS o
      ON t.created_at = o.created_at AND t.id > 126
      OR t.created_at < o.created_at
ORDER BY
    t.created_at DESC LIMIT 30;
```

Explanation: Basically it's needed for pagination as when users go to the next page it would show them 30 stories that were created before the specified id. When I sort the stories by created_at they become random, so I need to get the next 30 rows after a specific row which I accomplished with the above query.
126 is the id of the last story on the previous page which will be a variable in the actual code.

So when I try to use it in Laravel Eloquent whatever I do I just cannot make it work.

I've tried

```
$result = App\Story::join(DB::table('stories AS last_story')->find($previous_last_post_id), function($join)
        {
            $join->on('stories.created_at', '=', 'last_story.created_at')
            ->where('stories.id', '>', 'last_story.id')
            ->orWhere('stories.created_at', '<', 'last_story.created_at');
        })
        ->get()
```

Which gives me

> ErrorException in Grammar.php line 39: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Changing the subquery to

```
DB::table('stories AS last_story')->where('id', $previous_last_post_id)->get()
```

gives me:

> ErrorException in Grammar.php line 39: Array to string conversion

Gave up and also tried raw query:

```
$result = DB::select("SELECT t.*
FROM
        stories AS t
    JOIN
        ( SELECT created_at
          FROM stories
          WHERE id = 126
        ) AS o
      ON t.created_at = o.created_at AND t.id > 126
      OR t.created_at < o.created_at
ORDER BY
    t.created_at DESC LIMIT 30")
```

but that gave me

> FatalErrorException in e969125ed5dcf92ec33b84157c0eb37a line 88: Call to a member function toFormattedDateString() on string

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `get()` which returns array, try using `first()`

Comment: You mean in the subquery? ( making it DB::table('stories AS last_story')->where('id', $previous_last_post_id)->first() )

That returns "ErrorException in Grammar.php line 39:
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string". :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not use laravel's built in pagination?

```
$stories = App\Story::orderBy('created_at')->simplePaginate(30);
```

It will track the current page number with a URL parameter.

You can print the previous/next buttons with:

```
{!! $stories->render() !!}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination

Comment: Didn't know Laravel had pagination implemented. It's a good suggestion but if I add 30 new stories and the user clicks the next page button he will see the same stories he just saw, that is the reason I'm trying to use the above query, to save the last story that the user saw, so whatever happens he will actually see the next story next.

Comment: Oh that _is_ a special case. That's fast content creation. You're probably not going to want to use an eloquent sub query for a database the size you would quickly have. It will get slow.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that created_at is in the same order as the id column? It would probably be faster / more predictable to query by the last id instead of last timestamp.

Comment: You already queried for the previous record. You don't need a subquery, just put the value you already have as a parameter in a where condition.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the only way I made it work was:

```
DB::select('
    SELECT t.id
    FROM
        stories AS t
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT created_at
            FROM stories
            WHERE id = ?
        ) AS o
    ON t.created_at = o.created_at AND t.id > ?
        OR t.created_at < o.created_at
    ORDER BY t.created_at DESC LIMIT 30
', [$previous_last_post_id, $previous_last_post_id]);
```

I had created an almost identical eloquent query:

```
DB::table('stories')
    ->select('stories.id')
    ->join(DB::raw("(SELECT id, created_at FROM stories WHERE id = 126) as last_story"), function($join)
    {
        $join->on('stories.created_at', '=', 'last_story.created_at')
        ->where('stories.id', '>', 'last_story.id')
        ->orWhere('stories.created_at', '<', 'last_story.created_at');
    })->orderBy('stories.created_at', 'DESC')->take(30)->get();
```

but it returned wrong results, so I guess it's impossible to avoid using raw sql here.